# Hiding nil values, understanding why Go fails here

Tags: pointers, go, interface, null

I fail to understand how to correctly assure that something is not `nil` in this case:

```
package main

type shower interface {
  getWater() []shower
}

type display struct {
  SubDisplay *display
}

func (d display) getWater() []shower {
  return []shower{display{}, d.SubDisplay}
}

func main() {
  // SubDisplay will be initialized with null
  s := display{}
  // water := []shower{nil}
  water := s.getWater()
  for _, x := range water {
    if x == nil {
      panic("everything ok, nil found")
    }

    // First iteration display{} is not nil and will
    // therefore work, on the second iteration
    // x is nil, and getWater panics.
    x.getWater()
  }
}
```

The only way I found to check if that value is actually `nil` is by using reflection.

Is this really wanted behaviour? Or do I fail to see some major mistake in my code?

[Play link here](http://play.golang.org/p/jHHXZbLH7e)

Comment: this is in the FAQ, using the `error` interface as an example: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The problem here is that `shower` is an `interface` type. Interface types in Go hold the actual value and its *dynamic* type. More details about this: [The Laws of Reflection #The representation of an interface](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.).

The slice you return contains 2 non-`nil` values. The 2nd value is an interface value, a (value;type) pair holding a `nil` pointer value and a `*display` concrete type. Quoting from the [Go Language Specification: Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value `nil`.

So if you compare it to `nil`, it will be `false`. If you compare it to an interface value representing the pair `(nil;*display)`, it will be `true`:

```
if x == (*display)(nil) {
    panic("everything ok, nil found")
}
```

This seems unfeasible as you'd have to know the actual type the interface holds. But note that you can use reflection to tell if a non-`nil` interface value wraps a `nil` value using [`Value.IsNil()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsNil). You can see an example of this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ONtgvUbFYHb).

**Why is it implemented this way?**

Interfaces unlike other concrete types (non-interfaces) can hold values of different concrete types (different static types). The runtime needs to know the dynamic or runtime-type of the value stored in a variable of interface type.

An `interface` is just a method set, *any type* implements it if the same methods are part of the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the type. There are types which cannot be `nil`, for example a `struct` or a custom type with `int` as its underlying type. In these cases you would not need to be able to store a `nil` value of that specific type.

But *any type* also includes concrete types where `nil` is a valid value (e.g. slices, maps, channels, all pointer types), so in order to store the value at runtime that satisfies the interface it is reasonable to support storing `nil` inside the interface. But besides the `nil` inside the interface we must store its dynamic type as the `nil` value does not carry such information. The alternate option would be to use `nil` as the interface value itself when the value to be stored in it is `nil`, but this solution is insufficient as it would lose the dynamic type information.

> Some people say that Go's interfaces are dynamically typed, but that is misleading. They are statically typed: a variable of interface type always has the same static type, and even though at run time the value stored in the interface variable may change type, that value will always satisfy the interface.

In general if you want to indicate `nil` for a value of `interface` type, use explicit `nil` value and then you can test for `nil` equality. The most common example is the built-in [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) type which is an interface with one method. Whenever there is no error, you explicitly set or return the value `nil` and not the value of some concrete (non-interface) type error variable (which would be really bad practice, see demonstration below).

In your example the confusion arises from the facts that:

- you want to have a value as an interface type (`shower`)
- but the value you want to store in the slice is not of type `shower` but a concrete type

So when you put a `*display` type into the `shower` slice, an interface value will be created, which is a pair of (value;type) where value is `nil` and type is `*display`. The *value* inside the pair will be `nil`, not the interface value itself. If you would put a `nil` value into the slice, then the interface value *itself* would be `nil` and a condition `x == nil` would be `true`.

**Demonstration**

See this example: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h7-7jMLBxcM)

```
type MyErr string

func (m MyErr) Error() string {
    return "big fail"
}

func doSomething(i int) error {
    switch i {
    default:
        return nil // == nil
    case 1:
        var p *MyErr
        return p // != nil
    case 2:
        return (*MyErr)(nil) // != nil
    case 3:
        var p *MyErr
        return error(p) // != nil because the interface points to a
                        // nil item but is not nil itself.
    case 4:
        var err error // == nil: zero value is nil for the interface
        return err    // This will be true because err is already interface type
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 4; i++ {
        err := doSomething(i)
        fmt.Println(i, err, err == nil)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 <nil> true
1 <nil> false
2 <nil> false
3 <nil> false
4 <nil> true
```

In case 2 a `nil` pointer is returned but first it is converted to an interface type (`error`) so an interface value is created which holds a `nil` value and the type `*MyErr`, so the interface value is not `nil`.

Comment: that's a pretty... big fail isn't it? How can I write a library that provides interfaces that way? I could assure that it works correctly if the users provides correct types with nil value. 

I guess 
if x == (shower)(nil) 
would make sense but that is just shocking..

Comment: There is nothing shocking about it. Your return a slice of two interface values, both are non-nil. One of those non-nil interface values contains a nil value. The interface value _has_ to be non-nil to contain anything, even a nil. You can either fix it like icza suggested, or redesign your API, e.g. not returning a slice of interfaces.

Comment: @sharpner You can provide a library which uses/returns values of interface types. But if the value is "missing", return `nil` explicitly.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to redesign the api. Maybe a typedef something []shower will get me further or I don't know yet. But I really learned something quite new about go today. 

My example simplifies the real problem somewhat. In the final implementation, the  user of my library has to implement getWater() and therefore can make mistakes. 

So, since I got to assume that this will happen, I needed to assure that no nil values are in the slice. I anticipated that users can return pointer to structs or structs that implemented the interface....

Comment: A nil pointer is not an invalid value.  Note that you can call methods on nil pointers just fine:  http://play.golang.org/p/Agd8eIwaKZ   Try reading my post about nil pointer and nil interfaces, it may help: http://npf.io/2014/05/intro-to-go-interfaces/#toc_4

Comment: @icza I understand that this topic is a bit old. But I can't really understand why this is allowed as implicit coercion. Wouldn't it be more understandable to produce fully nil interface pointer from nil structure pointer? Or to check only value pointer against nil? Pike et al were saying so much about removing all unobvious and controversial things. And yet they leave this pretty much bug. Because it effectively allows to produce reference with broken invariants.
Calling methods over nil pointers is such a rare case, and more like a hack, that I don't consider it as a valid explanation.

Comment: @Target-san In that case a coder could no long check an interface variable against `nil` to verify that it was truly completely `nil`, that it held no dynamic type information, and you'd simply move this entire class of tricky behavior in a slightly different problem space. IOW, there's no simple/obvious answer here, because sometimes you might want to know if the value is nil and sometimes you might want to know if both type/value are nil.

Comment: @AndrewN Thanks for explanation. Though I found the answer on go-nuts group. Brief: Go uses pointers, and not references. For reference, `nil` is like `NaN` for floats. But for pointer `nil` is just yet another value. The difference seems to be semantical, because references and pointers usually have same representation under the hood.

Answer (score 15):

Let's think of an interface as a pointer.

Say you have a pointer `a` and it's nil, pointing to nothing.

```
var a *int // nil
```

Then you have a pointer `b` and it's pointing to `a`.

```
var b **int
b = &a // not nil
```

See what happened? `b` points to a pointer that points to nothing. So even if it's a nil pointer at the end of the chain, `b` does point to something - it isn't nil.

If you'd peek at the process' memory, it might look like this:

```
address | name | value
1000000 | a    | 0
2000000 | b    | 1000000
```

See? `a` is pointing to address 0 (which means it's `nil`), and `b` is pointing to the address of `a` (1000000).

The same applies to interfaces (except that they look a bit different [in memory](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)).

**Like a pointer, an interface pointing to a nil pointer would not be nil itself**.

Here, see for yourself [how this works with pointers](http://play.golang.org/p/jXkZUUEukm) and [how it works with interfaces](http://play.golang.org/p/xK96QxrgQ8).

Answer (score 0):

I'll take an alternative route to answer your *concrete* question, by providing the exact answer you were looking for:

Replace the check:

```
if x == nil {
    panic("everything is ok. nil found")
}
```

with:

```
if _, ok := x.(display); !ok {
    panic("everything is ok. nil found")
}
```

The idea here is that we are trying to convert the interface type (shower) to the concrete type display. Obviously the second slice item (d.SubDisplay) is not.

Comment: While this satisfies the original question, it defeats the purpose of an interface, since it only works if a display type is used.