# Null vs nil in golang?

Tags: pointers, go, interface, null

I ran into a strange bug today. I had a function:

```
func Foo(s *someStruct) {
    fmt.Printf("s is %v\n", s)
    if s!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("s is not nil")
        ...
    }
}
```

I would call the function like:

```
var s *someStruct
Foo(s)
```

And then I decided to convert the structure into interface:

```
func Foo(s someStructInterface) {
    fmt.Printf("s is %v\n", s)
    if s!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("s is not nil")
        ...
    }
}
```

Which gave me a strange output:

```
s is null
s is not nil
```

While I expected to get `s is nil`, which is what I was getting usually. What is the difference between null and nil in this scenario in Go and how can I check if something is null or nil to execute the code properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here#29138676).

Comment: The output from your interface example is `s is <nil>` and `s is not nil`.

Answer (score 4):

An interface value contains a reference to a type and a value. In the following code:

```
var s *someStruct
Foo(s)
```

the interface value passed to Foo contains a reference to the type `*someStruct` and a nil.

The statement `fmt.Printf("s is %v\n", s)` outputs `s is <nil>` because of the following:
The `%v` format prints a value using the default format for the type. The value `s` contains a pointer type. The default format for a pointer type is `%p`. The `%p` format prints nil pointers as `<nil>`.

The expression `s != nil` evaluates to true because an interface value is equal to nil if and only if the type reference is nil.  In this case, the interface value references the type `*someStruct`.

Comment: I don't understand where the explicit word `null` came from. It's not a construct of Go at all.

Comment: I get this distinction and can extend that to explain the behavior of `Printf` however, I wouldn't consider this as answering the question so I recommend elaborating on that.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I would guess there is a special case in `fmt` for `%v` with interface types however like I said, MuffinTop should explain that since he didn't really answer the question as much as point out some details about interfaces.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I tried to write a short playground for this, and didn't get `null` as an output.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer interesting... Perhaps the answer is wrong. I was about to do the same until this answer was provided but maybe I should look into it a bit more :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: "null" shouldn't come from the fmt package. It's likely a custom type, with slightly incorrect terminology, something like http://play.golang.org/p/CRFKJxEkGE

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I elaborated the answer as you suggested.  I am assuming that "null" in question is a typo and should read "<nil>" as pointed out in comment.  If "null" is printed, then someStruct has a `String() string` method or some other customization used by the fmt package.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Couple interesting things at work there. Someone writing poorly in their custom types `String()` implementation makes a lot more sense than a special case for the `%v` format specifier.