# Historical reference on why Go creators choose to not treat `nil` as `false`

Tags: go

Why did Go creators choose to not treat `nil` as `false`? What why did they think it is better to explicitly compare values to `nil`? Is there a reliable source that would explain why is that is Go? What was their opinion? What was the logic behind this decision?

I'm looking for a historical reference.

---

E.g.:

```
f, err := os.Open(name)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Than to implicitly cast `nil`s to `false` like in many other languages:

```
f, err := os.Open(name)
if err {
    return err
}
```

As of now, the latter would give:

```
non-bool err (type error) used as if condition
```

Comment: false isn't nil, and by reflexivity of identity, nil isn't false.

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion *is* the only argument here. As you have guessed from that thread, neither option is any better than the other. Indeed, all matters of programming style are *inherently subjective*, and ultimately it is up to the language designers to decide what they should or should not include in a language. It isn't necessarily about personal taste, though; in general the Go authors design the language based around what they feel leads to better code in the general case, even if it means abandoning their personal favorite idioms.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you form doing `type Err bool` and then `func (e Err) Error() { "Im an error" }`.   In that case, false is actually an error.   Obviously, it's unlikely anyone writes that code.  But languages with a truthiness concept implicitly impose some standard meanings behind non-boolean data (0/1 being false/true for example).  The Go authors chose to be explicit rather than implicit here probably due to it simplifying the language as well as not wanting surprises in general

Comment: @DavidBudworth do you have a canonical source in regard of their decision?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here

Comment: @sanmai I do not, I was more drawing conclusions based on other design decisions made by the language creators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some languages did that and it caused too many problems. It's primarily a violation of principle of least surprise. Some of the problems are:

- All non-nil values would evaluate to `true`. A pointer to `false` boolean value would evaluate to `true`. All of that would create new and larger set of complications, aka more bugs.
- Assigning a boolean to `nil` would be valid. Comparing a boolean to `nil` would be valid. That creates a semantic confusion. More bugs.
- Code would be harder to read because it hides the intent. It's impossible to tell from an expression if you want to check a boolean's value or assert "non-nilness" of some other type of variable. More bugs.
- Omitted operands in comparison operations in expressions would compile fine, making identifying bugs harder. Think about `if a == '3' && b { .. }` kind of cases where you forget to add the comparison so `b` always evaluates to `true` even if it's not what you intend. More and more bugs.

Go people probably thought about that, and concluded that code with fewer bugs is better.

There could be a shortcut though just to propagate the error to the caller such as:

```
require f := os.Open(name)
// if the call returns error, return error
```

EDIT: I'm happy to report that Go team is considering [a very similar approach to what I suggested](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-error-handling-overview.md), in Go 2. Only they used the keyword `check` instead:

```
check f := os.Open(name)
// if the call returns error run the declared error handler 
// which in turn, can return the error or do something else about it.
```

Comment: If only they can do that only `nil` would evaluate to `false` with everything else being the same

Comment: @sanmai that wouldn't help much. it would only eliminate the first case given in the item. still there are tons of scenarios only that would lead to.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't find an exact reason in any of the golang documentation or developer discussions, the closest reason is simply that that absence of a value (nil) *should not* be interpreted as false. This is also in line with the fact that golang is a very opinionated language, and that its authors felt that not casting types when evaluating for true/false would lead to better quality of code.