# golang: reflect.ValueOf(x).Type() always equals to reflect.TypeOf(x)?

Tags: go

To me these two seems to be always equal. Then why bother putting dynamic type information into interface type? Since it can be obtained from dynamic value.

Comment: but if i don't have a value.

Comment: The answer to your question is in my answer to this question: [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here)

Comment: Often you only have a `reflect.Value` to work with, and you need the `reflect.Type`.