# Check if interface value is nil in Go without using reflect

Tags: reflection, go, interface, null

I need to check if an **interface** value is `nil.

But by using **reflection** it is giving me an error:

> reflect: call of reflect.Value.Bool on struct Value.

Through `nil` it is not giving an **error** for `nil` value.

Comment: Related question, please read answers there: [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here)

Comment: Normaly you should try to avoid to use the reflect package. Why do you want to check if the interface is nil? Maybe the usage of an interface is not optimal and you shuold use an implementation of your interface.

Answer (score 19):

Interface is a pair of `(type, value)`, when you compare a interface with nil, you are comparing the pair (type, value) with nil. To just compare interface value, you either have to convert it to a struct (through type assertion) or use reflection.

do a type assertion when you know the type of the interface

```
if i.(bool) == nil {
}
```

otherwise, if you don't know the underlying type of the interface, you may have to use reflection

```
if reflect.ValueOf(i).IsNil() {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two things:
If y is the nil interface itself (in which case y==nil will be true), or if y is a non-nil interface but underlying value is a nil value (in which case y==nil will be false).

[Here's](https://play.golang.org/p/BjDd1ko94E) an example.