# How can v == nil return false and reflect.ValueOf(v).IsNil() return true at the same time?

Tags: go

Here's some code:

```
var v interface{}
v = (*string)(nil)

// Reflect says it is nil
val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
if val.IsNil() {
    fmt.Println("val is nil")
} else {
    fmt.Println("val is not nil")
}

// This says it is not nil
if v == nil {
    fmt.Println("v is nil")
} else {
    fmt.Println("v is not nil")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/apyPa4CNZ6

The output is:

> val is nil
>
> v is not nil

How is this possible? Is v nil or not?

Also, if you change the first two lines with

```
v := (*string)(nil)
```

then the output clearly states that the variable is nil.

Right now in my project I have a function that accepts a argument of type interface{} and I can't reliably check if it is nil with a simple v == nil. I would like to avoid using the reflect package.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From golang.org](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error):

> Under the covers, interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type
>   and a value. The value, called the interface's dynamic value, is an
>   arbitrary concrete value and the type is that of the value. For the
>   int value 3, an interface value contains, schematically, (int, 3).
>
> An interface value is nil only if the inner value and type are both
>   unset, (nil, nil). In particular, a nil interface will always hold a
>   nil type. If we store a nil pointer of type *int inside an interface
>   value, the inner type will be *int regardless of the value of the
>   pointer: (*int, nil). Such an interface value will therefore be
>   non-nil even when the pointer inside is nil.

You can try `fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", v, v)`. It prints `(<nil>, *string)`.

When you change first two lines to `v := (*string)(nil)`, `v` is just a pointer, not an interface.