# Why interface type doesn't provide an "IsNil" method?

Tags: pointers, go, interface, null

First let's consider the following:

```
func process(body io.Reader) {
    fmt.Printf("body == nil ? %+v\n", body == nil)
}

func main() {
    var body *bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Printf("body == nil ? %+v\n", body == nil)
    process(body)
    process(nil)
}
```

And here's the output:

```
body == nil ? true
body == nil ? false  // Did you get this right?
body == nil ? true
```

Another example:

```
type Container struct {
    Reader io.Reader
}

func processContainer(container Container) {
    fmt.Printf("container.Reader == nil ? %+v\n", container.Reader == nil)
}

func main() {
    var body *bytes.Buffer
    processContainer(Container{Reader: body})
    processContainer(Container{Reader: nil})
}
```

Output:

```
container.Reader == nil ? false // Did you get this right?
container.Reader == nil ? true
```

The explanation for this is at https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error.

A naive solution is to make the `== nil` test just return true if the interface object contains `nil` value.  But this would violate transitivity of `==`, as it would assert two objects with nil value but different interface types true under `==`.

**However, I wonder if there should be an `IsNil()` method on all interface types, which would solve this issue?**

Another example, this line from Go http client, can catch you unexpectedly:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L545

So if you call it like this

```
var body *bytes.Buffer
http.NewRequest(method, path, body)
```

You'll get a nil pointer exception, even though, by the look of the source code, this shouldn't happen.

**Edit**

Sorry I referenced the wrong line of the Go http source, now corrected.
But the example still holds.

**Edit 2**

I've highlighted my question to make it clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Please note this question is about why "IsNil()" isn't provided in Go as a method.  The "duplicated" question doesn't go this way.

Comment: You can use `== nil` on all interface values to test if they are equal. The confusion in your case comes from that inside `process()` you check if the _interface_ value is `nil`, while in your `main()` function you check the **non-interface, pointer** value. The interface value is automatically, implicitly created when the pointer is passed to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First read this related question: [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

You can check if the interface value itself is `nil` by comparing it to `nil`.

If you want to check if the value wrapped inside a non-`nil` interface is `nil`, you can use reflection: [`reflect.Value.IsNil()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsNil).

See this modified example:

```
func process(body io.Reader) {
    fmt.Printf("process(): body == nil ? %t\n", body == nil)
    if body != nil {
        fmt.Println("\tINSIDE IsNil():", reflect.ValueOf(body).IsNil())
    }
}

func main() {
    var body *bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Printf("main(): body == nil ? %t\n", body == nil)
    process(body)
    process(nil)
    process(&bytes.Buffer{})
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PX8IDo-gXS)):

```
main(): body == nil ? true
process(): body == nil ? false
    INSIDE IsNil(): true
process(): body == nil ? true
process(): body == nil ? false
    INSIDE IsNil(): false
```

If you want a "unified" `IsNil()` function which tells if either is `nil`:

```
func IsNil(i interface{}) bool {
    return i == nil || reflect.ValueOf(i).IsNil()
}
```

Comment: Hi icza, thanks for your answer.  I didn't realize the method is inside reflect package.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that reports if an interface contains any `nil`. Note that `reflect.Value.IsNil()` panics if the type doesn't have a nil value, so some checking on the kind must be done before calling it.

```
func isNil(x interface{}) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Map, reflect.Ptr, reflect.UnsafePointer, reflect.Slice:
        return v.IsNil()
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Here's a working example in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/RHzu3VVj4Zd

Answer (score -1):

The following is clearly based on Paul Hankin's answer, a tad of what icza wrote and the sources of reflect/value.go where `func (v Value) IsNil() bool` is defined. Do not trust the source, I am a newbie taking advantage of Cunningham's law! I would have just commented but I do not even have 50 points (-:

```
func isNil(x interface{}) bool {
    if x == nil {                                 // nil with no type.
        return true
    }
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    switch v.Kind() {                             // reflect.Invalid for nil
    case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Map, // 1st case of v.isNil
        reflect.Ptr, reflect.UnsafePointer,       
        reflect.Interface, reflect.Slice:         // 2nd case of v.isNil
        return v.IsNil()
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```