# Nil pointer to struct not deep equal to nil?

Tags: pointers, go, types, interface, null

If I have a struct containing a `nil` pointer of type `A`, using `reflect.DeepEqual` to check if that property is `nil` will result in `false`, which strikes me as odd behaviour.

```go
type Container struct {
    O *Obj
}

type Obj struct {
    Message string
}

var c Container
eq := reflect.DeepEqual(c.O, nil)
fmt.Printf("O value: %v, is nil: %t", c.O, eq)
// Prints: "O value: <nil>, is nil: false"
```

Specifically, I am marshaling a JSON object into a struct, where I would like to test that a specific property is `nil` when the corresponding JSON structure does not contain it. If `reflect.DeepEqual` is not the way to go, how should I do this?

Comment: You are right .. let look at documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual . At first paragraph is answer to your question -  Values of distinct types are never deeply equal. And rest of the answer is here https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you pass to [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) is wrapped in an `interface{}` value (if it's not already that):

```
func DeepEqual(x, y interface{}) bool
```

`interface{}` values will be compared, where the first parameter value **is not `nil`**, only the value wrapped in it.

An interface value is represented as a `(type; value)` pair. The first value you pass to `reflect.DeepEqual()` is a pair of `(type; value)` being `(*Obj, nil)`, and the 2nd value is `nil`. They are not equal. The second value lacks type information.

If you compare it to a "typed" `nil`, it will be `true`:

```
reflect.DeepEqual(c.O, (*Obj)(nil)) // This is true
```

See this example:

```
fmt.Println("c.O:", c.O)
fmt.Println("c.O == nil:", c.O == nil)
fmt.Println("c.O deep equal to nil:", reflect.DeepEqual(c.O, nil))
fmt.Println("c.O deep equal to (*Obj)(nil):", reflect.DeepEqual(c.O, (*Obj)(nil)))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vqXVOZpxNN)):

```
c.O: <nil>
c.O == nil: true
c.O deep equal to nil: false
c.O deep equal to (*Obj)(nil): true
```

See this question for a deeper insight:

[Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

If you want to check if the value wrapped inside a non-`nil` interface is `nil`, you can use reflection: [reflect.Value.IsNil()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsNil).

For more details see: [Why interface type doesn't provide an "IsNil" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895862/why-interface-type-doesnt-provide-an-isnil-method/43896204#43896204)

Comment: Thanks for the link on interfaces, I learned something new today!