# How to return custom errors without causing problems with nil values

Tags: pointers, go, error-handling, interface, null

I have implemented a custom error type and do get strange behaviour with regard to nil values. When I do pass the custom error along as standard error interface, this is never recognized as nil, even if the custom error was returned as nil.

Have a look at this little test program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type CustomError struct {
    Code int
}

func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(e.Code)
}

func FailCustom(dofail bool) *CustomError {
    if dofail {
        return &CustomError{Code: 42}
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func WrapFailCustom(dofail bool) error {
    return FailCustom(dofail)
}

func main() {
    err := WrapFailCustom(false)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("err is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("err is not nil")
    }
}
```

Same in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7bqeDw5B5fU

**This does actually output "err is not nil"**.

I would have expected the nil value of type *CustomError to be implicitly cast to a nil value of type error. Can anybody explain to me, why this is not the case and how to correctly propagate nil values of custom error types?

**Edit:**
Explanation for this can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) as pointed out by Iain Duncan

To further explore the issue, let's consider the following modification to WrapFailCustom:

```golang
func WrapFailCustom(dofail bool) error {
    err := FailCustom(dofail)
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

This does actually return "err is nil": https://play.golang.org/p/mEKJFyk5zqf

I do feel really bad with depending on this as solution, as it is easily forgotten when working with function that do spit out my custom error. Is there better way of making custom errors that does prevent this "ambiguity" from being possible to happen? The obvious solution of just using the basic error type all the time, seems really inconvenient for the code that consumes functions like WrapFailCustom, so I would like to avoid this...

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Comment: There is a really good gopher con talk about the different types of nil, including this common error where an interface pointer nil I'd not the same as an interface nil. https://youtu.be/ynoY2xz-F8s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For background, see [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676); and [Go FAQ: Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)

Go requires you to be explicit about types and conversions (e.g. you can't add a value of type `int32` to a value of type `int`), but interface conversions and automatic interface value creation is exception to this rule. Whenever a value of interface type is required, you may use any value whose type implements (satisfies) the interface type, and the interface value will be automatically created for you.

Your function:

```
func WrapFailCustom(dofail bool) error {
    return FailCustom(dofail)
}
```

`WrapFailCustom()` has a return type `error`, and you try to return the result of the `FailCustom()` function, whose return type is `*CustomError` which is not the same as `error`! This should raise a red flag!

What / how will be returned? An interface value of `error` type will be automatically created! `*CustomError` implements `error`, so it's all good, but as you experienced, if the pointer is `nil`, this implicit value wrapping will not result in an interface value being `nil`, but rather a non-`nil` interface value wrapping the value `nil` and the type `*CustomError`.

The solution?

### Taking care of the root cause

Is it really justified / does it have any value for `FailCustom()` to have a return type other than `error`? If not, easiest would be to deal with the "problem" right where it originates from:

```
func FailCustom(dofail bool) error {
    if dofail {
        return &CustomError{Code: 42}
    }
    return nil
}
```

And then all your problems go away. If you follow the "Go way" to return errors using the `error` type, this is perfectly enough and satisfying. You don't even need the `WrapFailCustom()` function anymore.

### Manually accounting for it in `WrapFailCustom()`

If you do need `FailCustom()` to return the custom `*CustomError` type, then you need to account for it "manually" in `WrapFailCustom()`. I would write it this way:

```
func WrapFailCustom(dofail bool) error {
    if customErr := FailCustom(dofail); customErr != nil {
        return customErr 
    }
    return nil
}
```

(Note that I deliberately used a different `customErr` name and not `err`, signalling that it's not of type `error`, and care should be taken how it will be converted to `error`.)

### Using a custom `error` type that is an interface type

If you want to / need to use your custom error type, another good approach would be to create an interface type that describes the "extra" functionality it incorporates:

```
type CustomErr interface {
    Error // Embed error interface
    Code() int
}
```

And then we also need the implementation of this `Code()` method:

```
func (e *CustomError) Code() int { return e.Code }
```

What's the use of this?

The root cause will be dealt with by returning a value of this *interface* type (and *not* a pointer):

```
func FailCustom(dofail bool) CustomErr {
    if dofail {
        return &CustomError{Code: 42}
    }
    return nil
}
```

The implicit interface value will be created in `FailCustom()`.

Moreover, `WrapFailCustom()` becomes needless / useless. `FailCustom()` returns a value that is both an `error`, and you can get the `Code` from it using its `Code()` method. The returned value is aleady an interface value, and it *is* an `error`, you can use it where an `error` value is needed. The concrete type `CustomError` can even be made unexported (hidden).

Related to this approach, check out [Dave Cheney: Don’t just check errors, handle them gracefully](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully), especially the section titled: **Assert errors for behaviour, not type**.