# Golang returning nil does not return nil

Tags: go, error-handling

I created a custom error type to wrap errors around for easier debugging in Golang. It works when there are errors to print, but now it is causing a panic.

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/VOo5DOIg1zt)

```
type Error struct {
    ErrString string
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
    return e.ErrString
}

func Wrap(err error, str string) *Error {
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    e := &Error{
        ErrString: str + err.Error(),
    }
    return e
}
```

When I call a function an it doesn't return an error, I should still be able to wrap the error.

The expected behavior is that if the error is nil, it should simply ignore it, unfortunately it does the opposite.

```
func foo() error {
    err := bar()
    return Wrap(err, "bar called")
}

func bar() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := foo()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Found error %v\n",err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("No Errors")
}
```

I expect it to print `No errors`. Instead it prints `Found error <nil>` even though the error is nil.

Comment: because Wrap gives a pointer to `nil` and not `nil` itself?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Comment: See duplicate: [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138676/1705598)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if err != nil
```

Is comparing a the err variable to a nil `error` , but its actually a nil `*Error`

Changing the code to

```
err:=foo()
var  nilerror *Error = nil
if err != nilerror {
    fmt.Printf("Found error %v\n",err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("No Errors")
```

Yields the predicted result.

Comment: Now it makes sense. my Wrap function was returning a `*Error` nil, not an `error` nil.

Comment: is it possible to change the custom error so that it will work with (if err != nil), instead of having to check against a declared nil pointer?

Answer (score 2):

> [type error](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error)
>
> The error built-in interface type is the conventional interface for
>   representing an error condition, with the nil value representing no
>   error.
>
> ```
> type error interface {
>     Error() string 
> }
> ```

---

The value of `err` of `interface` type `error` is not nil. It is the value `nil` of type `*main.Error`. In fact, `err != nil && err.(*Error) == nil` is `true`

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func error1() {
    err := foo()
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %v %v\n", err, err, err == nil, err.(*Error) == nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Found error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("No Errors")
}

func error2() {
    err := foo()
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %v %v\n", err, err, err == nil, err.(*Error) == nil)
    if err != nil && err.(*Error) != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Found error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("No Errors")
}

type Error struct {
    ErrString string
}

func (e *Error) Error() string {
    return e.ErrString
}

func Wrap(err error, str string) *Error {
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    e := &Error{
        ErrString: str + err.Error(),
    }
    return e
}

func foo() error {
    err := bar()
    return Wrap(err, "bar called")
}

func bar() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    error1()
    fmt.Println()
    error2()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/nwNRa2sNwj0

Output:

```
*main.Error <nil> false true
Found error <nil>

*main.Error <nil> false true
No Errors
```

Comment: Then how could I rewrite the Wrap function to take the type into consideration?

Comment: It took a while but now I understand. Basically for my case, Wrap will return error not my custom `Error`.

Comment: @Ibu: No. `foo`, not `Wrap`, will return type `error`, not your custom type `*Error`. `error` is an interface type.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `Error` type implements the `error` interface, the easiest solution, is to return an `error` in `Wrap()`:

```
func Wrap(err error, str string) error {
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    e := &Error{
        ErrString: str + err.Error(),
    }
    return e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change foo() return value to *Error

```
func foo() error {
    err := bar()
    return Wrap(err, "bar called")
}
```

Or:

```
func Wrap(err error, str string) error{
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    e := &Error{
        ErrString: str + err.Error(),
    }
    return e
}
```