# Comparison between empty interfaces in Golang

Tags: go, interface, comparison

According to the [specification:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if
>   they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both
>   have value nil.

```
var err error 
var reader io.Reader
```

As far as understand, `err` and `reader` have different dynamic types (`error` and `io.Reader`) and therefore are not comparable.

```
fmt.Println(err == reader)
```

will cause a compile error:

> invalid operation: err == reader (mismatched types error and io.Reader)

If it is true, why `Println` command outputs the same results for both variables? Why both are `nil`?

```
fmt.Printf("reader: %T", reader) // nil
fmt.Printf("error: %T", err) // nil
```

**EDIT** `reflect.TypeOf(err)`or `reflect.TypeOf(reader)` will also output `nil`. I do not understand why the output is the same if the types are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that interface values are comparable, but you can only compare values that are assignable to each other (more precisely, one is assignable to the other). Quoting from [Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> In any comparison, the first operand must be [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the second operand, or vice versa.

You can't assign an `error` value to an `io.Reader`, and you can't assign an `io.Reader` value to an `error` either, so you can't compare them.

They may or may not store the same dynamic value, if you want to compare those, first covert both to `interface{}`, so you can compare them, e.g.:

```
fmt.Println(interface{}(err) == interface{}(reader))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xTIyifnoFyP)):

```
true
```

Note: actually it would be enough to convert only one of them to `interface{}`, because that way the the other value will become comparable to the type of the one you converted to `interface{}` (any value is convertible to `interface{}`), so it would also be enough to do:

```
fmt.Println(interface{}(err) == reader)
```

Testing the comparison with non-`nil` interface values:

```
type x int

func (x) Error() string            { return "" }
func (x) Read([]byte) (int, error) { return 0, nil }

err = x(0)
reader = x(0)
fmt.Println(interface{}(err) == interface{}(reader))

reader = x(1)
fmt.Println(interface{}(err) == interface{}(reader))
```

Now output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cyWydXN9oA0)):

```
true
false
```

Also don't forget that a `nil` interface value does not equal to a non-`nil` interface value holding a `nil` dynamic value. For details, see [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

**Edit:**

The [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package prints the value inside the interface, not the interface value. Quoting from package doc of `fmt`:

> Regardless of the verb, if an operand is an interface value, the internal concrete value is used, not the interface itself.

Same goes with [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf): it returns the dynamic type, but if you pass a `nil` interface value to it, it returns `nil` so the `fmt` package will print `nil`. Quoting its doc:

> TypeOf returns the reflection Type that represents the dynamic type of i. If i is a nil interface value, TypeOf returns nil.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have edited my question to clarify the point, could you please have a look?

Comment: But if the dynamic type of both `reader` and `error` is the same (`nil`) why they are not comparable?

Comment: @AyZu Because none of them is assignable to the other (they have different static type: `error` and `io.Reader`). And the spec requires one-way assignability.

Comment: OK, thank you! I was confused with static type and dynamic type. They have the same dynamic type `nil` and therefore `reflect.TypeOf()` outputs the same result, but they have different static types and therefore they are not comparable.