# How to detect whether a struct pointer is nil in golang?

Tags: pointers, go, interface, null, compare

As is shown by the following code: `n := localplugin.NewPluginNet()`, the type of `n` is `localnet.Net`, which is a interface implemented by the struct pointer `*localnet.DomainSocket`. Function `func NewPluginNet() localnet.Net` returns a nil pointer to `n`.

```
var n localnet.Net    
n = localplugin.NewPluginNet()
fmt.Println("----> ", n)
if n == nil {
    fmt.Println("n is nil")
}else{
    fmt.Println("n is not nil : ",  n)
}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(n), reflect.TypeOf(nil), n)
```

The following is the output of the code above.

```
---->  <nil>
n is not nil :  <nil>
*localnet.DomainSocket <nil> <nil>
```

Why does n is not nil ?

===================================

```
var n1 *localnet.DomainSocket
n1 = nil
fmt.Println(">> ", n1)
if n1 == nil {
    fmt.Println(">>n1 is nil")
}else{
    fmt.Println(">>n1 is not nil : ",  n)
}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(n1), reflect.TypeOf(nil), n1)
```

However, it's correct for this case:

```
>>  <nil>
>>n1 is nil
*localnet.DomainSocket <nil> <nil>
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 10):

Why isn't `n` `nil`? Type of `n` is an interface type (`localnet.Net`) which is a wrapper for a `(type; value)` pair. The interface value may be non-`nil` even if it wraps a `nil` value. See [Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

To answer the question in title: you may use reflection to tell if a non-`nil` interface value wraps a `nil` value (e.g. `nil` pointer):

```
reflect.ValueOf(someValue).IsNil()
```

Example:

```
type reader struct{}

func (*reader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) { return 0, nil }

func main() {
    var r io.Reader = (*reader)(nil)

    fmt.Println(r, r == nil)
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(r).IsNil())
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ONtgvUbFYHb)):

```
<nil> false
true
```