# first argument to append must be a slice; have untyped nil

Tags: go, null, append, slice

I'm a newbie Go programmer confused by the below behaviour. I expected the program to fail at `t2` with error

> first argument to append must be a slice; have untyped nil

but Go is happy when passing in nil as first parameter to append when it's a parameter to a method?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Thing struct {
    data []string
}

func NewThing(extra []string) Thing {
    return Thing{
        data: append(extra, "b"),
    }
}

func main() {
    t := NewThing([]string{"a"})
    fmt.Println(t.data) // [a b]

    t2 := NewThing(nil)
    fmt.Println(t2.data) // [b]

    //_ = Thing{ // build failed: first argument to append must be a slice; have untyped nil
    //  data: append(nil, "b"),
    //}
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Cxi7fRHu3Wi

Is this just a convenience feature or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1295) discusses a proposal to make `append(nil, slice)` valid (dates back to 2010 but may provide some extra context).

Comment: Related: [Hiding nil values, understanding why Go fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-go-fails-here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a convenience that the capacity and length of a nil slice is zero.  From there, append works as normal when passed a nil slice.

The call `append(nil, "b")` does not compile because `nil` has no type. The compiler cannot determine the type of the result because the slice argument does not have a type.

The call `append(extra, "b")` works when `extra` is `nil` because `extra` is a typed value (a `[]string`). Given the slice type, the compiler knows that the result is `[]string` and that the appended elements must be assignable to `string`.

The call `append([]string(nil), "b")` also works because the expression `[]string(nil)` is a typed value.

Comment: That makes sense, it works when the compiler knows the type of the slice. Thank you!