# Get reflect.Value of nil pointer type

Tags: go, pointers, reflection

Using the Go `reflect` package I'd like to get a `nil` pointer of a particular type, for example I'd like a `reflect.Value` that represents `*int` with a value of `nil` not `*0`

I'm currently getting the zeroed value like this but this is `*0` not `nil`

```golang
// varType is a reflect.Type
reflect.New(reflect.PtrTo(varType).Elem())
```

Will give me a zero value, e.g. *0 for `*int`

But what I can't quite workout is now to get a `reflect.Value` of say type `*int` and it be `nil` not `*0`

I understand why `.Set(reflect.ValueOf(nil))` does not work. Perhaps I've missed a crucial step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reflect.Zero()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Zero) instead of [`reflect.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#New). `reflect.New()` allocates a value of the given type, and returns a pointer to it (wrapped in [`reflect.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value)).

`reflect.Zero()` does not allocate a new value, it returns the zero value of the given type (wrapped in `reflect.Value`). So if you pass the [`reflect.Type`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type) descriptor of `*int`, or any other pointer type, since the zero value for pointer types is `nil`, you get back a `nil` pointer.

For example:

```
var i int
varType := reflect.TypeOf(i)
v := reflect.Zero(reflect.PtrTo(varType)).Interface()
fmt.Printf("Type: %T, Value: %v\n", v, v)

if p, ok := v.(*int); ok {
    fmt.Println("v holds *int, its value is:", p)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/7Yp8gNiNW1F)):

```
Type: *int, Value: <nil>
v holds *int, its value is: <nil>
```

Do note however that you have to call [`Value.Interface()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Interface) to get a value out of `reflect.Value` (to leave the reflection world). Also note that this returned interface value (it has type `interface{}` or `any`) will **not** be `nil`, but it packs a `*int` type and a `nil` pointer value. For details, see [Hiding nil values, understanding why Go fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-go-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

Comment: thanks, I actually had `reflect.Zero(reflect.PointerTo(varType))` but I think I'd been overthinking/confusing myself as this does exactly what I wanted/expected. Thanks for the detailed answer!