# Dynamic type not cleared when reassigning variable - is this a bug?

Tags: go, interface, specifications

There's a well known quirk in Go where an interface holding a nil value does not equal nil. It's because under the hood the interface is a composite of dynamic type and value, and it is only nil if both are nil. So `(*MyStruct)(nil) != nil` but `(nil)(nil) == nil`. It's explained much better in [this blog](https://glucn.medium.com/golang-an-interface-holding-a-nil-value-is-not-nil-bb151f472cc7).

I found something related to this behaviour which surprised me, here: https://goplay.tools/snippet/VF8oWt9XvO8. Code is also reproduced below.

It seems that if you reassign a variable that has a dynamic type assigned, the dynamic type is remembered and persists to the new value. This seems unexpected to me, I think reassigning variables should overwrite all past state.

I checked the language spec but it's a bit ambiguous: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block ... Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Unclear if this means just the value, or the value plus the dynamic type.

Is this behaviour intended in the language, or some side-effect of the runtime re-using memory for variable reassignment and not clearing all state?

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type CustomError struct{}

func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    return "err"
}

// ===================

func FuncThatReturnsCustomError() *CustomError {
    return nil
}

func FuncThatReturnsCustomErrorAsErrorInterface() error {
    // although the underlying returned value is nil, the return value from this func != nil
    // https://glucn.medium.com/golang-an-interface-holding-a-nil-value-is-not-nil-bb151f472cc7
    return FuncThatReturnsCustomError()
}

// ===================

func main() {
    // Assign a non-nil value to err (value is nil, dynamic type is not)
    err := FuncThatReturnsCustomErrorAsErrorInterface()
    fmt.Printf("err == nil: %v                                    false because although the value is nil, the dynamic type is not nil (expected)\n", err == nil)

    // Call func where return type is a pointer to a struct and and returns nil
    // It is nil, as expected, this call is just to provide a comparison with the call after
    newlyDeclaredErr := FuncThatReturnsCustomError()
    fmt.Printf("newlyDeclaredErr == nil: %v                        true because func returned nil (expected)\n", newlyDeclaredErr == nil)

    // Exactly the same call as above, but reusing the original err variable instead of declaring a new one
    // Back to not nil, unexpected
    err = FuncThatReturnsCustomError()
    fmt.Printf("original err reassigned == nil: %v                false presumably because err remembered its old dynamic type even after reassignment (unexpected)\n", err == nil)

    // Reassign err again, but explicitly to nil rather than by calling a function that returns nil. This time it's nil again
    err = nil
    fmt.Printf("original err after assignment to nil == nil: %v    true, expected but not consistent with the case above\n", err == nil)
}
```

Comment: Also note that using pointers to the empty struct is an incredibly stupid idea as all your non-nil *CustomError might be equal.

Comment: `CustomError` is obviously simplified for the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unexpected" part from you is this:

```
err = FuncThatReturnsCustomError()
```

You expect the result to be `nil`. `err` is a variable of interface type (`error`), and `FuncThatReturnsCustomError()` has a return type of `*CustomError`. That is **not** an interface type, it's a concrete type (a pointer to `CustomError`). Since it returns a non-interface value, when assigned to a variable of interface type, it has to be wrapped into an interface value. This is where a non-`nil` interface value will be created. This has nothing to do with "remembering" or "retaining" the old type information.

If you use a function that has an interface result type such as this:

```
func returnNilErr() error {
    return nil
}
```

And testing it:

```
err = returnNilErr()
fmt.Printf("result of returnNilErr() == nil: %v\n", err == nil)
```

You get (try it on the [Go Playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/sMLCQwmIhRN)):

```
result of returnNilErr() == nil: true
```

Because `returnNilErr()` already has an interface result type (`error`), so its return value doesn't need to be packed into an interface value, it can be used as-is when assigning to the `err` variable.

See related / possible duplicate: [Hiding nil values, understanding why Go fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-go-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

It's also mentioned in the [Go FAQ: Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error)

Comment: I see, so the real difference is that `err` has type `error` but `newlyDeclaredErr` has type `*CustomError`. I think that must be it, because if I change `newlyDeclaredErr := FuncThatReturnsCustomError()` to `var newlyDeclaredErr error = FuncThatReturnsCustomError()` then `newlyDeclaredErr` is indeed not nil.

Comment: Yes. If you use `newlyDeclaredErr := FuncThatReturnsCustomError()`, then type of `newlyDeclaredErr` will be `*CustomError`, and no interface wrapping will happen, `newlyDeclaredErr` will be a `nil` pointer. If you use `var newlyDeclaredErr error = FuncThatReturnsCustomError()`, then type of `newlyDeclaredErr` is an interface type, so the returned `nil` pointer has to be wrapped in a non-`nil` interface value.

Comment: I would include the link to [the classic FAQ entry](https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error) as well.

Comment: I would also highlight that `nil` might be a bit unfortunate term picked by Go to stand for the zero value of any interface type as it may force a programmer to think it's a pointer whereas it's actually two pointers (and before Go gained a precise GC, sometimes even a pointer and a non-pointer value). I have no idea what other term could be both concise and recognizable, though ;-)

Comment: @kostix `nil` itself doesn't indicate pointer right away, there are countless other non-pointer types in Go that have `nil` as their zero value, such as slices, functions, channels, maps (although some of them may indeed be implemented as pointers under the hood, but not all, and that's also only an implementation detail). Nevertheless, this non-`nil` interface wrapping a `nil` pointer is for sure confusing for newcomers, but once you get bitten and understand why, it usually not an issue anymore.